# How to chain views when guideline is present

Tags: android

I am trying to build an activity which has a guideline in it and I also want to chain elements in the activity.

When I do spread value for app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle property, it works fine.

However if I change a value to packed, that's where everything that is attached to a guideline on one side follows the chain and a guideline and the other side does not.

How can I achieve that both sides follows the same rules. On the second image I want a riht side of the guidline to be alliged the same way as the left side

spread

[image]

packed

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title_label"
        style="@style/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        style="@style/add_step"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_description_label"
        style="@style/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_description"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_description" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/txt_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/spn_milestone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/txt_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_milestone_label"
        style="@style/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Milestone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/spn_milestone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/spn_milestone" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_milestone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_start_day"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_priority_label"
        style="@style/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Priority"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/spn_priority"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/spn_priority" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_priority"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_end_date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/txt_description"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_start_date_label"
        style="@style/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Day"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_start_day"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_start_day" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_start_day"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/spn_milestone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/spn_milestone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spn_milestone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_end_date_label"
        style="@style/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="End Date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_end_date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_end_date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_end_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/spn_priority"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/spn_priority"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spn_priority" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Show your xml code. As we see on the 2nd screenshot you have a lot of warnings.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii this is my xml